# Function in Reactjs .NET is never reached - how to call a simple arrow function inside render?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am setting up my first ReactJS.net application, and followed the tutorial on the site.

I have built a bit more on it, and I have the following code inside my `App.jsx` file:

```
let test = () => {
    console.log('called!');
    return "<p>Testing</p>";
} 

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">

                Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
                <test /> // tried both but neither worked
                {test}
      </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

If I am not wrong, similar code usually works in a normal React.js application. However, this simply doesn't even call the test method (console log is never reached and I don't see the output from my `test` function.

**Now, what am I doing wrong here? :-)**

Why am I not seeing the `<p>Testing</p>`?

**The generated JS code is as follows:**

```
// @hash v3-310AECBD0B84ED139C81E87801CA7DBDFA284566
// Automatically generated by ReactJS.NET. Do not edit, your changes will be overridden.
// Version: 3.3.0 (build 8c1c474) with Babel 6.7.7
// Generated at: 01-04-2018 17:37:43
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var test = function test() {
    console.log('called!');
    return "Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing ";
};

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    displayName: "CommentBox",


    render: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "commentBox" },
            "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.",
            React.createElement("test", null),
            test
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(CommentBox, null), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `test` function is just that, a function.  JSX doesn't know what to do with that.  `<Test />` would presumably instantiate a React component. And `{test}` would interpolate some javascript value.  Your call does neither.  It sticks a function on the page which doesn't render and doesn't execute.

If you want to call your `test` function, you call it like you would any other javascript function: `{test()}`.